# How can I use Low pass filter here?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors, lowpass-filter

I am new for this. I want to reduce the frequency of my sensors. I somewhere read that high frequency of sensors can be reduce by Low pass filter.
my code is

```
if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            float[] rotationMatrixFromVector = new float[16];
            float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
            getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrixFromVector, sensorEvent.values);
            final int screenRotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            switch (screenRotation) {
                case ROTATION_90:
                    remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrixFromVector,
                            AXIS_Y,
                            AXIS_MINUS_X, rotationMatrix);
                    break;
                case ROTATION_270:
                    remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrixFromVector,
                            AXIS_MINUS_Y,
                            AXIS_X, rotationMatrix);
                    break;
                case ROTATION_180:
                    remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrixFromVector,
                            AXIS_MINUS_X, AXIS_MINUS_Y,
                            rotationMatrix);
                    break;
                default:
                    remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrixFromVector,
                            AXIS_X, AXIS_Y,
                            rotationMatrix);
                    break;
            }
            float[] projectionMatrix = arCamera.getProjectionMatrix();
            float[] rotatedProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0);
            this.arOverlayView.updateRotatedProjectionMatrix(rotatedProjectionMatrix);
            //Heading
            float[] orientation = new float[3];
            getOrientation(rotatedProjectionMatrix, orientation);
```